# Codesigning error when updating from iOS 3 to iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, code-signing, ios3.0

I am trying to update iOS 3 application to iOS 8. All functionality in my application are work fine on simulator but when i try to deploy my application on my iPad which has iOS 5, facing some error. I fixed all setting like deployment target to iOS 5 and other basic setting. ERRORS which i face

1. Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No code signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“searchme”) were found.
2. CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.1'

Reference to fist error i have create provisional profile with a name "searchme" and 
Bundle identifier - `com.damyant.searchme`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Reset your code signing and make sure the bundle ID isn't changed.
2. The deployment target should be same as or less than the iphoneos/iphonesimulator.
3. Clean the project, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a developer account for debugging applications on iPhone.

After getting developer account first thing to do is to create a request for Certificate from you key chain access and upload this certificate in create new certificate section in you developer account.

[Steps to create certificate](http://seventhsoulmountain.blogspot.jp/2013/09/ios-code-sign-in-complete-walkthrough.html)

after that create a provisioning profile against that certificate.(Download this provisioning profile if required. xcode should automatically take care of this if click in fix while building),[Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile.html)

Also you need to register your device to the development account. Try this [Link](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-New-Device-to-Your-Apple-Developer-Portal)